# Flex sidebar: how to grow to 100% of height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I´m building a sidebar using CSS flex and I need it to grow vertically to fill the whole screen vertical height. Here is a skeleton of what I´m doing.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vewqu7rc/)

```
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  . align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content-main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

<div class='app'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    This is sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='content-header'>
      Content Header
    </div>
    <div class='content-main'>
      This is the main content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it pretty close by assigning the full viewport height to your container and then removing `flex: 1` from `.content` children.

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  . align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  background-color: grey;
}

.content-main {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='app'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    This is sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='content-header'>
      Content Header
    </div>
    <div class='content-main'>
      This is the main content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set `font-size: 300px;` in the main content, the sidebar is shorter than the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gxkezny9/

One of the parent containers wasn't 100% height

Answer (score 1):

The proper usage of Flexbox, is to make the `app` take full height by either use `height: 100vh`, or give *html/body* a height, `html, body { height: 100%` } so the `app`'s height work as expected.

Second, as you use `align-items: flex-start` all items will initially align at the top, but by adding `align-self: stretch` to the `sidebar`, it will fill its parent's height.

*Note, for flex row item you should not use `height: 100%`, you should use the `align-*` properties.*

*Note 2, the set `flex: 1` on `content-header` and `content-main` doesn't have any affect, unless their parent `content` has a height higher than their summed height. i.e. if to change the `app`'s `align-items` to `stretch` (and if, the `align-self` on `sidebar` can be removed)*

*Note 3, the `flex: 1` won't work properly in IE, use `flex-grow: 1` instead, or assign all values, where `flex-basis` should be `auto`, i.e. `flex: 1 1 auto`*

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;                 /*  changed  */
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: stretch;            /*  added  */
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  flex: 1;                        /*  for IE, "flex-grow: 1" or "flex: 1 1 auto" 
 */
  background-color: grey;
}

.content-main {
  flex: 1;                        /*  for IE, "flex-grow: 1" or "flex: 1 1 auto" 
 */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='app'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    This is sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='content-header'>
      Content Header
    </div>
    <div class='content-main'>
      This is the main content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```